# Counting most freq. user in an array

Tags: java

```
    int totalEnrolled = studentEnrollments.size();
    String mostFreqUser = "";
    int count = 0;

    System.out
            .println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Spring 2016 Enrollment~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    for (String userName : studentEnrollments.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Student: " + userName);
        ArrayList<String> courses = studentEnrollments.get(userName);
        String courseMessage = "Courses: ";
        String seperator = "";


        // looping through courses
        for (String singleCourse : courses) {
            // counting how many courses were enrolled
            count++;
            courseMessage += seperator += singleCourse;
            System.out.println(courseMessage);
            seperator = ",";
        }

    }


    System.out.println("Total students enrolled: " + totalEnrolled);
    System.out.println("Total courses enrolled: " + count);
    System.out.println(mostFreqUser);
}

}
```

Hello, I was wondering how would I make a counter for the most frequent user. Everytime the for loop runs It would calculate who put there username the most. Also one more thing, how come the output prints multiple courses not just one for each name. For example instead of printing a course line for each courses it prints it twice.

for example the expected output looks like

Student: josh
Courses: cs170, cs180

but the output looks like

Student: josh
Courses:cs170
Courses:cs170,cs170

Thank you, please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

Move the print statement outside the inner `for` loop.

Note: It's spelled "sep**a**rator".

Don't do a chained `+=`.

**NOTE:** If you see the same course name listed multiple times for a student, then your `studentEnrollments` Map-List is likely wrong, not your displayed code.

The following code also shows how to find the student with the largest number of courses (aka the "mostFreqUser"). There can of course be more than one student with that many courses, but only the first is shown.

```
System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Spring 2016 Enrollment~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
int courseTotal = 0;
int maxCourseCount = 0;
String maxCourseStudent = "";
for (String student : studentEnrollments.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Student: " + student);
    ArrayList<String> courses = studentEnrollments.get(student);
    String courseMessage = "Courses: ";
    String separator = "";
    for (String course : courses) {
        courseMessage = courseMessage + separator + course;
        separator = ",";
    }
    System.out.println(courseMessage);
    courseTotal += courses.size();
    if (courses.size() > maxCourseCount) {
        maxCourseCount = courses.size();
        maxCourseStudent = student;
    }
}
System.out.println("Total students enrolled: " + studentEnrollments.size());
System.out.println("Total courses enrolled: " + count);
System.out.println("Most frequent student: " + maxCourseStudent + " (enrolled in " + maxCourseCount + " courses)");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can use a Hashtable. Initialize your hashtable with a value of 1 whenever a user is seen for the first time. Subsequently, increment the hashtable count if a user is seen again. Finally, go through each element of the hashtable to find the largest value.

For the second part, you need to bring the second print statement outside of the for loop.

Comment: OP is already using a `Map` (hence the `keySet()` call in the outer `for` loop, so a student/user will only ever be seen once.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `courseMessage` in course loop. So it will print `courseMessage` for each course in course collection. That is why you're getting two inputs.

Also following statement will affect your output

```
courseMessage += seperator += singleCourse;
```

This should be written as

```
courseMessage += seperator + singleCourse;
```

---

**DEMO FOR += PROBLEM**

Suppose we have two courses in our list say `cs150` and `cs160`.
Initially,

```
courseMessage = "Courses : ";
separator = "";
```

For first course, `cs150`,

```
courseMessage += separator += singleCourse;
=>
couresMessage += separator = separator + "cs150";
=>
courseMessage += separator = "cs150";
=>
courseMessage += "cs150";
=> courseMessage = "Courses : cs150";
```

So after first iteration, `courseMessage` will be `Courses : cs150` and `separator` will be `cs150`. 
Here you modifies value of `separator` accidentally, which will reflect in consequent iteration and you will get unexpected output.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what taking += does?

Comment: Since `seperator` is cleared 2 lines down (`= ","`), the `+=` makes no functional difference, though it *is* bad coding and bad for performance, so it shouldn't be done.

Comment: @Andreas, You are right. Actually I did n't notice that :(